# try catch event doesn't show error in laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel-4, try-catch

Here is my code in which you can see that the where condition is empty for the delete command

```
     try{
            DB::table('t_users')->where('id', '=', '')->delete();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            return Functions::createErrorResponse(400, 'E200', $e->getCode() . ' - ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

but it doesn't show any kind of error here., if I make **some wrong table name** then it gives me the error as..

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "type": "E200",
        "message": "42S02 - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'globalops.t_charts' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `t_charts` where `id` = )"
    }
}
```

which is fine,

Can anyone give me the reason why it doesn't display any error even if I keep my code in try-catch event.
Am I supposed to do something else..?

Comment: I don't think it's an error to have `WHERE id = ""` in SQL. ;)

Comment: Exactly. You can pass an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

A `DELETE` statement will throw no error even if no rows match (are being deleted). However `delete()` will return a count of affected rows. I think you want to do something like this:

```
$affected = DB::table('t_users')->where('id', '=', '')->delete();
if($affected == 0){
    return Functions::createErrorResponse(400, 'E200', 'User not found');
}
```